# How to split by paragraph in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have texts like this:

```
['\n      2. Materials and Methods\n       2.1. Data Collection and Metadata Annotations\n      \n        We searched the National Center for Biotechnology Information (NCBI) Gene Expression Omnibus (GEO) database [15]']
```

I wish to split the string by paragraph.. meaning at least two `\n` in a row. I'm not sure that all cases of `\n` are separated by the same number of white spaces.

How can I define such regex of this sort `\n`+ multiple spaces + `\n`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split on `\n (any amount of spaces) \n` then:

```py
l = re.split(r'\n\s*\n', l)
print (l)
```

It leaves the spaces in your input left and right

```
['\n      2. Materials and Methods\n       2.1. Data Collection and Metadata Annotations',
 '        We searched the National Center for Biotechnology Information (NCBI) Gene Expression Omnibus (GEO) database [15]']
```

but a quick strip will take care of that:

```py
l = [par.strip() for par in re.split(r'\n\s*\n', l)]
print (l)
```

as it results in

```
['2. Materials and Methods\n       2.1. Data Collection and Metadata Annotations',
 'We searched the National Center for Biotechnology Information (NCBI) Gene Expression Omnibus (GEO) database [15]']
```

A bonus effect of `\s*` is that more than 2 successive `\n`s will be considered as 2-or-more, since the expression grabs as much as it can by default.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```py
>>> a = ['\n      2. Materials and Methods\n       2.1. Data Collection and Metadata Annotations\n      \n        We searched the National Center for Biotechnology Information (NCBI) Gene Expression Omnibus (GEO) database [15]']
>>> output = [i.strip() for i in a[0].split('\n') if i.strip() != '']
>>> output
['2. Materials and Methods', '2.1. Data Collection and Metadata Annotations', 'We searched the National Center for Biotechnology Information (NCBI) Gene Expression Omnibus (GEO) database [15]']
```